# iOS Obj-C. Posing correct solution?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am at a place in my application where essentially every ViewController has a local NSManagedObjectContext:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

and every segue passes the managedObjectContext via the same setter

```
[segue.destinationViewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Coming from Java, it would be easy to create an abstract class that each ViewController implementes. In Objective-c it doesnt seem like that is possible. What I am looking to do is have a base class that performs this passing, but basically anything that implements UIViewController will have this (including just a plain UIViewController as well as a UITableViewController).  Would it be possible/correct to have create an "abstract" class that poses as UIViewController that does this?

Update:

UIViewController+ManagedObjectContext.h

```
@interface UIViewController (ManagedObjectContext)
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@end
```

UIViewController+ManagedObjectContext.m

```
#import "UIViewController+ManagedObjectContext.h"
@implementation UIViewController (ManagedObjectContext){
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;    // This is not valid, cant have local variables
}
@synthesize managedObjectContext; // This is not valid, must be @dynamic
-(void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
    //How do you have a local NSManagedObjectContext?
}
@end
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for an objective-c Category. They are used to extend classes.

Comment: Class posing in Objective-C 1.0 was a ***mess***, so it has been removed in 2.0.  I don't think it was ever a part of the iOS NSObject class at all.

Comment: While I've never seen class posing in iOS, I have seen something similar to replace the UINavigationBar in navigation controllers.

Comment: I shouldn't say removed, rather deprecated (according to apple itself) in favor of categories and  method_setImplementation

Comment: that's what it was, a hack using method_setImplementation. fugly.

Comment: The problem I was having with a Category was that I am not sure how to have a local variable of type NSManagedObjectContext *. Typically I would just have a @serialize, but thats not possible in a Category. I am not able to have a local class object. How would you have a 'setManagedObjectContext' method? I will update the question with the problems...

Answer (score 5):

You can just make your own subclass of `UIViewController`, let's say `MOCViewController`, with the `managedObjectContext` property.  Then make all of your other view controllers be subclasses of `MOCViewController` instead of directly subclassing `UIViewController`.

If you really want to do it with a category, your category can use `objc_setAssociatedObject` to attach the managed object context to the view controller.

If you only really have one managed object context and you're just passing it around everywhere, consider just putting the context in a property of your application delegate, or in a global variable.

Comment: This was my first though, but then you would need one for each type, UIViewController, UIListViewController, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the managedObjectContext from a managed object rather than pass it separately.
Generally its more logical to pass the managed object.

For example:
Say you have a managed object called thing, you can get the managedObjectContext by calling

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc=[thing managedObjectContext];
```

Alternatively you can get the managed object context from the application delegate:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = delegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: This may be the best solution. I was running into the case where a ViewController did not have a ManagedObject, but was like 3 steps into a Navigation. I didnt realize you can just get the context from the AppDelegate. Even in this case though, it would be nice to have have to write that in the load of each class...